# Inserting value from database to dropdownlist fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, cascadingdropdown

I have state and city dropdownlists(cascaded) as below :

```
 protected void BindStateDropDown()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblState", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlState.DataSource = ds;
        ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
        ddlState.DataValueField = "StateId";
        ddlState.DataBind();
    }
    ddlState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
    ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
}


protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int StatId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCities", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatId", StatId);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlCity.DataSource = ds;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
    ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
}
```

which i use to insert values to the database as  below :

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", ddlState.SelectedItem.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", ddlCity.SelectedItem.Text);
```

This works fine and inserts the state and city in the database table.Now i try to show back the values on the edit page as below :

```
 ddlState.SelectedIndex = ddlState.Items.IndexOf(ddlState.Items.FindByText(rdr["State"].ToString()));
 ddlCity.SelectedIndex = ddlCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlCity.Items.FindByText(rdr["City"].ToString()));
```

The abpve code binds the state but not the City.The city dropdown still shows ---Select---.Once the city is bound, i should be able to select any other city/state and update it again.
 Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you please post the code that binds the comboboxes

Comment: Please bind first both combo box and after set selected Index.

Comment: use different datasets for ddlcity and ddlstate

Comment: Have you tried using this `dlState.SelectedValue = rdr["State"].ToString();`

Comment: @Suprabhat - No, it doesn't even bind the state

Comment: @Manraj- how do i change the city according the selected state then ?

Comment: you are using sane dataset for both. so one fills and other not

Comment: you have to use like ddlcity.selectedvalue = dscity.Tables[0].Rows[i]["state"].toString; and also you have to first get all rows using for loop

Comment: if you comment the first dataset then city will be bind and hence you know what are you doing dear

Comment: As your city dropdownlist is binded after selection of ddlState so you can first bind the ddlCity then assign value to that in edit page.

Comment: Please do share what's in stored procedure named `spCities` is it returning a single table or multiple table that would be lot more easier to indentity the cause of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ddlState.SelectedIndex = ddlState.Items.IndexOf(ddlState.Items.FindByText(rdr["State"].ToString()));
```

then set city value to hidden value hf_city

```
hf_city.Value = rdr["City"].ToString();
```

then close your reader and connection and then again call your function which is created on ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged

```
 int StatId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCities", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatId", StatId);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlCity.DataSource = ds;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
    ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));

 ddlCity.SelectedIndex = ddlCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlCity.Items.FindByText(hf_city.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another method for binding cityDropdownlist:

```
protected void BindCityDropDown(int StatId)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCities", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatId", StatId);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddlCity.DataSource = ds;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
    ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
}
```

Call this inside dropdownlistselected index change:

```
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int StatId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);
    BindCityDropdown(StatId);
}
```

Now in edit section bind citydropdownlist then assign value:

```
ddlState.SelectedIndex = ddlState.Items.IndexOf(ddlState.Items.FindByText(rdr["State"].ToString()));
int StatId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);
BindCityDropdown(StatId);
 ddlCity.SelectedIndex = ddlCity.Items.IndexOf(ddlCity.Items.FindByText(rdr["City"].ToString()));
```